# Creating collections in SOLR

Tags: java, solr, solrj

On the web searching for collections in SOLR i found only information about distributed search and so on but when  I understand the concept of correclty collections are running on the same server instance using the same schema but are logically completely separated. Is this correct?
So I can have 3 collections and searching on one collection won´t output results of another right? Would it be *possible* to search on more than one collection at once?

But my main priority: How do I create a second collection? Even a link to a good doc would be appreciated.
In my solr.xml i have

```
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="web-collection" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="web-collection" instanceDir="." />
  </cores>
```

Would it be sufficient to create a second core-entry and set different paths? like...

```
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="web-collection" host="${host:}" hostPort="${jetty.port:}">
    <core name="web-collection" instanceDir="web" />
    <core name="test-collection" instanceDir="test" />
  </cores>
```

What is the instanceDir about? Is it the index-directory relative to SOLR-Home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more information on setting up cores and how they work, please see the [Solr Wiki - CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) for more details and some examples.

Your example for adding the second core-entry is sufficient.

The instance directory is the index-directory relative to your SOLR home value.

Answer (score 7):

You can use multiple cores. Each core is a separate lucene index.
`instanceDir` is the location of the configuration files for that specific core, the folder that contains the `conf` directory, which contains `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` among others. You usually have a subfolder per core where the `solr.xml` is (SOLR_HOME) and use relative paths to refer to them within the `solr.xml` itself.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the REST API, you can create a new core using SolrJ.  After struggling to create one myself, here's what I ended up doing:

```
SolrServer aServer =  new HttpSolrServer("http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr");
CoreAdminResponse aResponse = CoreAdminRequest.getStatus(collectionName, aServer);

if (aResponse.getCoreStatus(aNewInstance.getCollection()).size() < 1)
{
    CoreAdminRequest.Create aCreateRequest = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
    aCreateRequest.setCoreName(collectionName);
    aCreateRequest.setInstanceDir(collectionName);
    aCreateRequest.process(aServer);
}
```

Comment: hello wisco, I am getting error in   aCreateRequest.process(aServer); statement. my if statement is like this if (aResponse.getCoreStatus(collectionName).size()< 1){}. please, give me suggestion for the issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your first comment.  If you removed that line from your if block, how is it throwing an exception?  Also, it's been a year and a half since I worked on this, so I don't remember it very well.  If I had to guess, I would say aNewInstance().getCollection() probably needs to return the name of the collection you're trying to find or create.

Comment: Wisco crew, no problem. I got it. If condition checks that core is not already available and it's brand new core.

Answer (score 0):

## **Tested with Solr 6.x**

Fortunately, there is now a standard option `create` of script `bin/solr` that is able to detect in which mode Solr is running in (standalone or SolrCloud), and then take the appropriate action (create a core or create a collection).

```
$ bin/solr create -help

Usage: solr create [-c name] [-d confdir] [-n configName] [-shards #] [-replicationFactor #] [-p port]
```

For example, assuming that you're running a recent version of Solr on port `8983`, create a new core just running:

```
bin/solr create -c collection1 -d /path/to/solr/conf
```

An important distinction has to be done for the confusion that sometimes happens between Collections and Cores. From the client perspective there are no differences, so create a core or collection depend on whether Solr is running in standalone (core) or SolrCloud mode (collection).

For a more complete distinction referer to [Solr Collection vs Cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044640/solr-collection-vs-cores)