# Solr core creation in solr cloud (solr 4.1.0)

Tags: solrcloud

I am trying to create core dynamically through my java appliction in solr cloud having two shard.

```
CloudSolrServer cloudSolrServer = new CloudSolrServer("localhost:9983", new LBHttpSolrServer  ("http://localhost:8983/solr"));
CoreAdminRequest.Create req = new CoreAdminRequest.Create() {

         private static final long serialVersionUID = -8825247378713661625L;

            @Override public SolrParams getParams() { 
            ModifiableSolrParams modifiableSolrParams =      (ModifiableSolrParams) super.getParams();
            modifiableSolrParams.set("collection.configName", "mycore"); 
            return modifiableSolrParams; 
            } 
        };

req.setInstanceDir("/solr/master/mycorepath"); 
req.setCollection("mycore");

CoreAdminResponse res = req.process(cloudSolrServer.getLbServer());
```

However i am getting the error:
**Specified config does not exist in ZooKeeper:mycore**

When I checked in the solr admin console I found the collection "mycore" is not completely created[i.e it does not have the folder symbol] and there is no config with the name "mycore".

**How do I go about this problem. What is the standard way for creating core dynamically in a 2 shard solr cloud (solr 4.1.0)?**

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully created collection with solr4.4 having two shards and no replicas using collections api

```
CloudSolrServer cs = new CloudSolrServer("localhost:9983");

CollectionAdminResponse res=CollectionAdminRequest.createCollection("testCollection", 2,   1, 1, "127.0.1.1:7574_solr,127.0.1.1:8983_solr", "myconf", null, cs);
```

This will create a collection with compositeID router

**myconf** is the configuration name that has been uploaded to zoo keeper during the cluster start up.

Answer (score 0):

I too am using Solr 4.1.0, and was having some trouble creating a core.  I'm only using one shard, but I answered another question along similar lines [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069841/creating-collections-in-solr/17820434#17820434)