# Solr Collection vs Cores

Tags: solr, lucene

I struggle with understanding the difference between **collections and cores**. If I understand it correctly, cores are multiple indexes. Collection consists of cores, so essentially they share the same logic in separation, i.e. separate cores and collections have separate end-points.

I have the following scenario. I create a backend for cloud service for several online shops. Each shop has a set of products, to which customers can add reviews. I want to index static data (product information) separately from dynamic information(reviews) so I can improve performance.

How can I best separate in Solr???

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the [SolrCloud Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Glossary)

> Collection:    A single search index.
>
> Shard:    A logical section of a single collection (also called
>   Slice). Sometimes people will talk about "Shard" in a physical sense
>   (a manifestation of a logical shard)
>
> Replica:    A physical manifestation of a logical Shard, implemented
>   as a single Lucene index on a SolrCore
>
> Leader:   One Replica of every Shard will be designated as a Leader to
>   coordinate indexing for that Shard
>
> SolrCore:    Encapsulates a single physical index. One or more make up
>   logical shards (or slices) which make up a collection.
>
> Node:    A single instance of Solr. A single Solr instance can have
>   multiple SolrCores that can be part of any number of collections.
>
> Cluster:     All of the nodes you are using to host SolrCores.

So basically a Collection (Logical group) has multiple cores (physical indexes).

Also, check the [discussion](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Terminology-question-Core-vs-Collection-vs-td4030232.html)

Comment: What is search index please?

Answer (score 43):

**Core**

In Solr, a `core` is composed of a set of configuration files, Lucene index files, and Solr’s
transaction log.

a Solr core is a
uniquely named, managed, and configured index running in a Solr server; a Solr server
can host one or more cores. A core is typically used to separate documents that have
different schemas

**collection**

Solr also uses the term `collection`, which only has meaning in the context
of a Solr cluster in which a single index is distributed across multiple servers.

SolrCloud introduces the concept of a `collection`, which extends the concept of a uniquely
named, managed, and configured index to one that is split into shards and distributed
across multiple servers.

Answer (score 19):

As per my understanding:

**In distributed search**,

**Collection** is a logical index spread across multiple servers.
**Core** is that part of server which runs one collection.

**In non-distributed search**,

Single server running the Solr can have multiple collections and each of those collection is also a core. So collection and core are same if search is not distributed.

**Summary**

1. Collection per server is called a core.
2. Collection is same as an index.
3. One Solr server can have many cores.
4. Collection is a logical index (Example usage for multiple collections: Say two teams in same group are not big enough to justify a full Solr server of their own. But they also do not want to mix their data in a single index. They can then create separate collections/indexes which will keep their data separate).
5. Its better to use a separate Solr Cloud rather than create collections if the data for a collection is big enough (not sure, comments please?)

Answer (score 11):

**Single instance**

On a single instance, Solr has something called a SolrCore that is essentially a single index. If you want multiple indexes, you create multiple SolrCores.

**Solr Cloud**

With SolrCloud, a single index can span multiple Solr instances. This means that a single index can be made up of multiple SolrCore's on different machines. We call all of these SolrCores that make up one logical index a collection.

A collection is a essentially a single index that spans many SolrCore's, both for index scaling as well as redundancy. If you wanted to move your 2 SolrCore Solr setup to SolrCloud, you would have 2 collections, each made up of multiple individual SolrCores.

Answer (score 6):

From [Solr Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology):

> Collections are made up of one or more shards.  Shards have one or
>   more replicas.  Each replica is a core. A single collection represents
>   a single logical index.

Answer (score 5):

This explains the use of cores and collections.

**Single instance**

When dealing with a single solr instance you query to `cores`.

The admin UI of a single Solr instance has no collection selector:

[image: Single Solr Instance]

**Solr Cloud**

When dealing with Solr Cloud you query to `collections`.
The collections are organized in different cores (replicas, shards) on different solr instances.

The admin UI of a Solr Cloud instance has a collection and core selector. But cores are technically instances, here:

[image: Solr Cloud instance]

Answer (score 0):

From the Solr docs:

> Usage: solr create [-c name] [-d confdir] [-n configName] [-shards #]
>   [-replicationFactor #] [-p port] [-V]
>
> Create a core or collection depending on whether Solr is running in
>   standalone (core) or SolrCloud   mode (collection). In other words,
>   this action detects which mode Solr is running in, and then takes
>   the appropriate action (either create_core or create_collection).